# What Apache server configuration(s) do I need to map directory name to domain?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, virtualhost

Say I have a folder ~/apache/ that contains two website directories:
www.website1.com
www.website2.com

Right now I have things set up using the sites-available and sites-enabled configurations which map domains to directories. I'd like to make it so that all I have to do is create a new directory and point the proper domain to my server.

I'll be honest and say I know little to nothing about server configurations. I think I need something along the lines of

`VirtualDocumentRoot ~/apache/%0`

in a configuration file. httpd.conf? apache2.conf? Or would it be best to put this in a separate config and include it in a main config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can potentially completed ditch name-based virtual hosting completely, turn off all your `sites-enabled` files, and put `VirtualDocumentRoot` in the main server config.

More likely, what you'll want to do is create a new vhost in `sites-available` and symlink it to `sites-enabled` normally, having it act as a catch all.  Naming is significant; it needs to be the first file alphabetically in order to be treated as a default.

So:

- Create an alphabetically-early file that will get loaded first, to be treated as default, such as `/etc/apache2/sites-available/0-dynamic`.
- Give the new vhost file some content like this:

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName catchall
      VirtualDocumentRoot /path/to/domains/%0
      <Directory /path/to/domains>
          Order Allow,Deny
          Allow from all
      </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- Enable it: `a2ensite 0-dynamic`. (if the default is still in place at `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`, rename it so it comes after the new one alphabetically.

This configuration will serve up the dynamically-configured sites from the `VirtualDocumentRoot`, but can be overridden and served by a different `<VirtualHost>` when that block has a `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` that matches the request.  This can be useful if your "blanket" vhost's settings are not appropriate for specific domains.

**Edit: (Adding some things I experienced trying to set this up that may be helpful. All credit goes to the original author!)**

**VirtualDocumentRoot**

If you get an error saying

```
Invalid command 'VirtualDocumentRoot', perhaps misspelled...
```

check to make sure the vhost_alias module is enabled. If it's not, run

```
>sudo a2enmod vhost_alias
```

**Handling leading www**

Add the following rules (be sure to replace example with your actual domain) to the 0-default file to handle www.example.com and example.com.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In this example, the www is stripped for all requests, so the directory should be example.com.

Comment: Will this work for www.website1.com and website1.com (without the www)?

And awesome info. I appreciate the thorough answer. Being able to configure specifics for certain domains is a good call. I'll be taking a look at this later tonight.

Comment: @loeschg No, it does not handle the www/no-www difference.  How do you want that to be handled - redirect one to the other?  Or serve the content for both?  If you're redirecting, that's probably best to handle with `mod_rewrite` to dynamically strip or add the `www` as desired.  If you want the content to be served, then you can either handle that in `mod_rewrite` or turn on `Options +FollowSymLinks` and create a symlink for `www.example.com` in the websites directory pointing to the `example.com` directory.